# Optimize Wrapfigure's output

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

I am including a wrapfigure in my document. My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{60mm}
%  \begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{Filter.jpg}
\caption{Χαμηλοπερατό Φίλτρο}
%  \end{center} \sq
  \label{fig:filter}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent Παράλληλα κατασκευάστηκε ένα φίλτρο αποκοπής υψηλών συχνοτήτων με συχνότητα     αποκοπής $f_c=5.9\,kHz$. Για την κατασκευή του παραπάνω φίλτρου(εικ. \ref{fig:filter})     χρησιμοποιήθηκε μια αντίσταση $2.7M\Omega,\,(1/2 W)$ και ένας κεραμικός πυκνωτής με     χωρητικότητα $10nF\,(3kV)$. Το φίλτρο παρεμβάλλεται μεταξύ του τροφοδοτικού υψηλής τάσης     και του ανιχνευτή.

\section{Μετρήσεις με τον ανιχνευτή $NTUASmm3$}

Κατά την διάρκεια των πειραματικών μετρήσεων με τον ανιχνευτή $NTUASmm3$,     χρησιμοποιήθηκε αέριο μείγμα $Ar-CO_2\rightarrow 70\%-30\%$, διότι το αποδοτικότερο $Ar-    CO_2\rightarrow 93\%-7\%$ είχε καταναλωθεί. Η χρήση αυτού του αερίου υπήρξε η αφορμή για να     δοκιμαστεί ο ανιχνευτής σε περιβάλλον μεγάλου ιονισμού. Η μεγαλύτερη κατ' όγκο ποσότητα     $CO_2$ θα κατευνάσει εν μέρει τον ιονισμό, αλλά θα προστατέψει τον ανιχνευτή
\end{document}
```

The output I get is

[image]

which is really ugly...
Any ideas on making it look a bit better?

Answer (score 2):

The `wrapfigure` environment accepts an optional argument, which is the number of lines of text that should be truncated due to the presence of the figure. Without this argument, the number of lines is sometimes calculated incorrectly, which seems to be the case here. So, I would try

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{60mm}
```

to begin with, and play around with the optional argument until the result is optimal.

**Edit**

Unfortunately, it is possible for a wrapfigure to end up in a location where there simply isn't a good setting for the number of truncated lines. An example of this is as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{60mm}
\centering
\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.25\columnwidth}
\caption{A nice figure}
  \label{fig:filter}
\end{wrapfigure}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
%\par\rule{0pt}{2ex}    % <--- uncomment to fix problem         
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad wrapfig]

If the number of lines is increased from 7 to 8, the section heading moves alongside the figure, and the result is horrible. Fortunately, such pathological cases are rare, so I suggest leaving this until your document is otherwise finished, and then fixing the problem either by adding a small rule as in the commented code above, or moving the figure if that fails to produce an acceptable result.

Comment: I forgot to mention...I tried this option but the thing is that there is a great ammount of space beneath the figure... Actually this is what I want to fix!

Comment: @Thanos --- I don't understand; the optional argument should allow you to reduce the space beneath the figure.

Comment: :You are right! That's why Itried this option at first, but it couldn't be fixed. I suspect that it has to do with the beggining of a new section, although I cannot tell for sure...

Comment: @Thanos --- ok I get it now. See if my edited answer helps at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! The tking is that it's not working. It doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: @Thanos --- the fix involving `\rule` works for the example I produced. Can you provide an example where it doesn't work, using Roman lettering? (I'm having trouble with the Greek characters in your example.)